# openmp working weird (job multiplied by number of physical cores)

Tags: c++, openmp

this is my test code

```
void test_code() {
  omp_set_num_threads(4);
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();

    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      printf("Hello World %d %d\n", tid, i);
  }
}
...
void CResizer::ThreadMain()
{
  test_code();

  MLINFO(ObjectName(), "%s started\n", __FUNCTION__);
  CBufferMonitor bufResize("Resizer (frames):", ObjectId());    
  ...
```

and result should be this

> Hello World 1 1
> Hello World 3 3
> Hello World 2 2
> Hello World 0 0

but this is my result is

> Hello World 0 0    Hello World 0 1
> Hello World 0 0    Hello World 0 1
> Hello World 0 2    Hello World 0 3
> Hello World 0 0    Hello World 0 1
> Hello World 0 2    Hello World 0 3
> Hello World 0 0    Hello World 0 0
> Hello World 0 1    Hello World 0 2
> Hello World 0 3    Hello World 0 0
> Hello World 0 1    Hello World 0 2
> Hello World 0 3    Hello World 0 0
> Hello World 0 1    Hello World 0 2
> Hello World 0 1    Hello World 0 2
> Hello World 0 3    Hello World 0 0
> Hello World 0 1    Hello World 0 2
> Hello World 0 3    Hello World 0 3
> Hello World 0 2    Hello World 0 3

Do you have any idea why it work like this?
My system has 8 core cpu, centos 7.5.

Comment: Can you post the entire code I have tried what you have posted and I am unable to reproduce your problem

Comment: What compiler (and openMP version) did you use? I was also unable to reproduce the problem...

Comment: i use gcc 7.3.1 and i just added "add_compile_options(-fopenmp)" to cmakeLists.txt

Comment: #dreamcrash, entire code is too many. in my code, intel IPP, pthread and SIMD are used

Comment: updated test code

Comment: @NamukKim, is this a new application? If you recently added another technology to your application , "add_compile_options(-fopenmp)", maybe this is a case of premature optimization. Did your application already work as expected before you introduced OpenMP? Do you have a set of tests to identify any regressions?

Comment: @DanielDearlove, no it is code for company app. and i tried other cmake script for openmp but didnt worked too. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12404666/16248362)
. Everything works fine except for openmp.

Comment: I think the only possible explanation is that `#pragma omp parallel` can only use one thread (e.g. no threads left or your code is inside a nested parallel region and nested parallelism is not allowed) therefore `tid` is always 0 and `test_code()` was called 8 times.

Comment: So my guess is that `CResizer::ThreadMain()` is executed simultaneously by 8 threads in your application. This will produce such an output. (BUT without the code it is hard to tell)

Comment: Why do you mix threads (pthread) and openMP? You should choose one of them.

Comment: @Laci several people were working together, so it became mixed. and before executing test_code(), there is only one CResizer thread

Comment: @NamukKim, I think Laci, myself and others are making the same point. Mixing OpenMP, pthreads and other libraries/technologies is resulting in unexpected interactions between them. Since you are using IPP, maybe you can refactor around TBB too since Intel makes both. TBB has a [parallel-for](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onetbb-documentation/top/onetbb-developer-guide/parallelizing-simple-loops/parallel-for.html) loop algorithm. Otherwise, using pthreads, maybe you can create some basic generic parallel algorithm wrappers such as a parallel-for loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to emphasize that the information (code sample) you provided is not enough to answer the question, but it may be possible to **guess** what is going on.

I think the only possible explanation is that `#pragma omp parallel` region in `test_code()` function can only use one thread (e.g. because no more threads available or your code is inside a nested parallel region and nested parallelism is not allowed) therefore `tid` is always 0. Moreover, the `test_code()` (i.e. `CResizer::ThreadMain()`) was executed by 8 threads, so the printout is repeated 8 times. Based on your function name (ThreadMain) it seems to be a plausible explanation, but as I mentioned without a minimal working example it is not possible to tell for sure. Anyway, I hope it helps to find the problem.

To give you an example, the following code will produce similar output like you sent:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
    
void test_code() {
  omp_set_num_threads(4);
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();

    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      printf("Hello World %d %d\n", tid, i);
  }
}
int main() {    
    #pragma omp parallel
    test_code();
}
```

Comment: first of all, thanks for answering my question. 
before executing test_code(), there is only one CResizer thread. however after execution, it is increased to 8.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. You mean that there is 8 `CResizer` thread, but `test_code()` is only called once?  What do you get if you just comment out `#pragma omp parallel` and `#pragma omp for` in `test_code()`?

Comment: yes, test_code() is called once. and without "omp_set_num_threads(4)", the result is same. it always create 7 more threads if i use openMP

Comment: OK. What do you get if you just comment out `#pragma omp parallel` and `#pragma omp for` in `test_code()` and do not change anything else (e.g. use openmp during compilation)? Do you get the expected result or is it printed 7 more times?

Comment: Based on your answer "it always create 7 more threads if i use openMP", it seems that if openMP is enabled `test_code()` is called 8 times, if openMP is not enabled `test_code()` executed only once. So your "mixed code" must have to contain other openMP directives which affects your code if openMP is turned on. I think `test_code()` is fine, but there are some "hidden" openMP directives somewhere in your program which changes its behavour if openMP is enabled. That's the reason I asked you to comment out openmp directives in `test_code()` and test it when openMP turned on in the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the [OpenMP Quick Reference Card](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMPRefCard-5.1-web.pdf), you created "a team of OpenMP threads that execute the region." All the OpenMP specifications can be found [here](https://www.openmp.org/specifications/).

The output still looks wrong even if you were executing the parallel section multiple times. That is because `i` is shared across all threads. Also, it is unclear why you are surrounding a parallel section with a `std::mutex` which identifies this as C++ code. You can also set the number of threads in the parallel section from the `#pragma` statement. Thus the following is probably sufficient:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    const int tid = omp_get_thread_num();

    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("Hello World %d %d\n", tid, i);
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel  "is because i is shared across all threads." this is not accurate, the OpenMP standard ensure that i will be private among threads. I have tested the OP's original code and I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: @dreamcrash, thanks for pointing that out. I looked at the code but I have not executed it. From the code fragment, it looks like `i` is shared because it is declared before the parallel section and not specified in the `#pragma`. If OpenMP duplicates stack variables by default then it is my mistake and I will own it. I will not change my answer so your comment remains in context.

Comment: Yep, OpenMP will create a private copy of it https://stackoverflow.com/a/67073601/1366871

Comment: thanks for answer me. but still the result is same. i think something unknown things seem to be affecting it.