# How to use "#pragma omp parallel for" correctly to get profit to fill the array Qvector

Tags: multithreading, qt, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm learning c++ and trying to make my own calculator with charting. In this part, when I try to fill an array with coordinates. I want to make it faster using multithreading. But when I did so, the code began to work much worse, slower. How can I solve the problem what am I doing wrong? By the way, it doesn't work at all without "#pragma omp critical"

```
    omp_set_num_threads(2);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (current = start; current < finish; current ++) {
        Calc b(a.get_string());
        double y_value = b.parsing((double)current/1000);
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            if (y_value > yL || y_value < yR) {
                x->push_back((double)current/1000);
                y->push_back(y_value);
            }
        }
```

x and y this is QVector.
Please try to express yourself as simply as possible because I'm just learning. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1):

The critical section is certainly not needed because the condition `y_value > yL || y_value < yR` can be done in parallel assuming `yL` are `yR` left unmodified and because `x` and `y` can be initialized with the size `finish-start` and you can then perform direct accesses on the vector like `x[current-start] = (double)current/1000;`. Also, please note that it is probably better to put `current` private using the clause `private(current)` in the parallel directive.

Comment: Since 'current' is the loop variable it is guaranteed by the OpenMP standard to be private

Comment: @dreamcrash I am never sure about this though I read the specification many time (and now it start to be too be for a basic quick search :p), so thank you for clarifying this point.

Comment: Yep, that used to be the case for me as well, but I got correct a few times by the expert Hristo Iliev. btw https://stackoverflow.com/a/67073601/1366871 shows the OpenMP reference.

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to do it thanks to you!

Comment: @GenrihFrank Great don't forget to make this answer as accepted.